# I want to use some pieces of C code in ROS, that uses C++ language

Tags: c++, c, ros, catkin

as the title says, I'm trying to use some C code in a .cpp file that i want to use in a ROS package.
Here is the code that i wrote for now:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"
#include "../include/heart_rate_monitor/wfdb.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sstream>


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "heart");
    ros::NodeHandle n;

    int i;
    WFDB_Sample v[2];
    WFDB_Siginfo s[2];

    if (isigopen("100s", s, 2) < 2)
        exit(1);

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (getvec(v) < 0)
            break;
        printf("%d\t%d\n", v[0], v[1]);

    }
    exit(0);
    return 0;
}
```

When i try to use catkin_make, i can see in the terminal some errors like

```
"heart.cpp:(.text+0xf4): reference not defined on "isigopen".
```

Because, clearly, the system cannot see the wfdb.h C library, although is placed in the include folder of the package.
Maybe i have to use some code like `#ifdef __cplusplus` and `extern C` or something?

If so, i really don't know how to use it, since I'm a super noob in coding!
Is there something else that i haven't considered?

Thank you in advance!

Marco

Comment: A .h file is not a library, but a header file. The library has an extension like .lib, .a, .so or .dll, and you have to link to it, not #include it.

Comment: Post your linker line!

Comment: I put both the library and the header in the same folder, but, as far as i know, i have to write #include in the ROS language. I searched for it and i supposed to be right. Am i wrong? Do i have to link the library in the CMakeLists.txt??

Comment: A header file (.h) generally contains a description of a library, and is usually accompanied with a library file (.lib) that actually contains the code.  The compiler will generate code, but then a linker will be used to pull in all the required libraries and create the executable.  For example, printf is declared (without any actual code) in the .h file stdio.h, but there will also be a library file that actually contains the code for printf.  Do you have a makefile that you can post?

Comment: yes, i have it? but it's very big because it's full of comments that teach you how to write the things. Should i post it as an answer?

Comment: yes, i have it without ? of course ;)

Comment: I found the problem! In the CMakeLists.txt i used the correct name of my library (libwfdb). But, it seems that's the ROS logic, the compiler/linker put  the suffix lib at every library file when it does the linking. In my case, since the "lib prefix" was already present because it's a part of the library name, the linking resulted in liblibwfdb, causing my errors! I simply deleted lib in my CMakeLists and all went fine! Thank you all for all your help! :)

Answer (score 2):

You should look to here get more information about code mixing : 
https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/mixing-c-and-cpp

```
   // C++ code
extern "C" void f(int); // one way
extern "C" {    // another way
    int g(double);
    double h();
};
void code(int i, double d)
{
    f(i);
    int ii = g(d);
    double dd = h();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but i don't understand so well your example. Maybe i have to follow the instructions of the other users? They said that maybe is a linking problem.

Answer (score -1):

This sounds like a linker problem, not a compiler problem.  Have you included the .lib on your linker line?

Comment: Do you mean in the CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: It was a kind of this problem! Thank you!